# regular expression with kleene closure

Tags: regular-languages, regular-expressions

my question is if my regular expression R is  1* that means the language accepted is {^,1,11,111,1111...}

---

in that case i don't understand the meaning what (R*)* means

Comment: Essentially $1^*$ means "any word consisting of any (finite) number of ones".

If R is a RE and L(R) is its language, then R^* is "any word consisting of the concatenation of any (finite) number of words in L(R)". 

For example if $R = a+b$ then $R^*$ contains the word "abba" as it is the concatenation of "a", "b", "b", and "a", all of which are in $L(R) = \{a, b\}$.

Going back to your case, you have $R = 1^*$ so $R^* = (1^*)^*$ is "any word obtained by concatenating any (finite) number of words containing only ones"... a convoluted way to say "any word containing only ones".

Comment: Oh..  I see you edited your comment. Glad the other thread helped.